# flash websocket + jetty

Tags: java, flash, websocket, jetty

I use jetty and I use websocket. 
I've tried to use flash websocket for IE8 and IE9, but I have some problems.
I'm trying to get flash policy file:
`WebSocket.loadFlashPolicyFile("xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:9999/policy")`
But it doesn't do any call to my servlet:

```
public class PolicyServlet extends GenericServlet {
    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("SEVERE");
    }
}
```

And in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>PolicyServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/policy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples how to use apache modules to serve policy files.  http://socketpolicyserver.com/ . Maybe its easier for you to use a Plug-In for IE9 http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com and/or jetty-websocket as your servlet implementation interface since youre already using jetty as your Web Server.